# Flutter property values of a Map all treated as strings

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I have a list like this `a = [{'one': 'one', 'two': null, 'three': [{'four': 'four'}]}]`

I send it to a function to use it in a post request which in the body should receive a Map, so what I did was this to `a[0]`, the problem is that I get this error `The getter 'length' was called on null`

I start to review and it treats all the property values as if they were Strings, even the nested list `'three': [{'four': 'four'}]`, I have tried to send the post in this way `http.post (url, body: (recurrence [0] as Map))` but it has not worked, it always gives me the same error, even if in the body I put the properties by hand in the `body: {'new property': a [0] [' tres']}`, how should one act to solve this problem? Thank you very much for your help

Code:

```
void _ordersGet() async {         
    await http.get(url).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        orders = jsonDecode(value.body);
      }
}
```

orders is sent to a new widget: `orderList(orders)`

orderList is a listView

```
ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      primary: false,
      itemCount: orders.length,
      itemBuilder: (orders, index) {
        return return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[              
          Text(orders[index]['facts']),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          Text('Cantidad : '),
          Text(orders[index]['ITEMS'][0]['jeans']),
          SizedBox(
            width: 4,
          ),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () => _reorderData(context, orders[index]),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.replay_outlined,
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              )),
        ],
      ),
        );
      },
    );
```

_reorderData is a function that make a get request, the info in shipped to ReorderModal

ReorderModal it only shows the information and has a button

```
void _reorderData(BuildContext ctx, order) async {
    var data;
    var url = 'serverAddress/${order['facts']}';
   
    await http.get(url).then((value) {
      data = jsonDecode(value.body);
      data[0]['CORPORATION'] = order['corporation'];

      showModalBottomSheet(
          context: ctx,
          builder: (_) {
            return ReorderModal(data);
          });
    }).catchError((onError) {});
  }

class ReorderModal extends StatelessWidget {
  final List data;
  ReorderModal(this.data);
  
  void orderSend(orderInfo) async {        
    var url = 'serverAddress';

    await http.post(url, body: orderInfo[0]).then((value) {

      print(jsonDecode(value.body));

    }).catchError((onError) {
      
      print(onError);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: Column(
              children: [                        
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              orderSend(data);
              //print(data);
            },
            child: Text('ONE Click'))
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

when i press the ONE Click button execute the function orderSend, orderSend make a post request and the problem described above

This is the simplified code, I know it must be something very simple, but it is giving me a lot of work to solve

Comment: Could you provide a **minimal** yet **complete** sample to reproduce your problem? My guess is that your problem comes from the way to decode a JSON String. Is the Data originally a JSON String?

Comment: I think that the problem is the listView.builder, i will make more tests